# Excel not discarding original data despite merging cells - causing problems with functions (e.g. sum)

Tags: excel, function, merge, sum, cells

When merging cells, Excel normally gives the message: "merging cells only keeps the upper-left values and discards other values".

In some cases this doesn't happen, and the data remains in the cells hidden behind the merged cell. (I am not using align across selection).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I have noticed it a few times in a sheet I am working on ([attached example](http://www.filedropper.com/160605excelmergedcellsproblem) and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cRzy.png)).

Answer (score 1):

If you 'paste special formulas' over a merged cell, Excel pastes formulas into all cells individually, but maintains the appearance of a merged cell.

Functions used across a 'merged' cell like this will therefore include all the data in the underlying cells.